# How to make always skype detect number on my site?

Tags: skype, skype4com

Is there any way to make skype always detect numbers on my site by including any header file or something and which number format is prefered that skype detects easily...[image: something like this]

Answer (score 1):

This is based on a browser extension. The users of your site will have to have it installed.

Comment: is the number format mentioned above in the pic is standard for skype number detection???

Comment: Yes it represents a US/Canada phone number which I'm sure skype will detect.

Comment: hmmmm means there is noway that all the browser detects the number on the site unless there is plugin installed on their browser???

Answer (score 1):

You could try using links with `tel:` or `skype:` schema, e.g.:

```
<a href="tel:0123456789">Call us</a>
```

More info [here](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/click-to-call-links-mobile-browsers)